# Use str_detect to find the ID of the novel Pride and Prejudice

Tags: r

Use str_detect to find the ID of the novel Pride and Prejudice.

How many different ID numbers are returned?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gutenbergr)
library(tidytext)
options(digits = 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to `filter` the rows based on the substring "Pride and Prejudice" in the 'title' column and get the number of distinct 'gutenberg_id' s with `n_distinct`.  If the ids are alreaydy unique, just do `summarise(n = n())`

```
library(gutenbergr)
library(stringr)
gutenberg_metadata %>%
  filter(str_detect(title, "Pride and Prejudice"))  %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(gutenberg_id))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#     n
#  <int>
#1     6
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198912/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-use-str-detect-to-find-the-id-of-the-novel-pride-a).

Comment: @akrun Hi, Can you assist with some questions?

Comment: @CooganPillay. Yes, pleases ask new questions